# Redirect to secure page is not happening after login with Spring Security oAuth + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have followed the [tutorial](http://www.thecuriousdev.org/spring-security-oauth2/) to learn Spring-Security With OAuth

Where i need to create a [Autherization Server](https://github.com/chiranjeevibmse/spring-learning/tree/master/AutherizationServer) and the [Client](https://github.com/chiranjeevibmse/spring-learning/tree/master/oauth-client) to Authenticate the User

When i go to secure page in client it will redirect to login page of the Autherization Server, after i give user name and password again it goes to login page itself

we can see the redirects as below
[image]

Can you help me what i have made mistake

Comment: That's because of the 401 for the favicon.ico You have to permit all access to the ico file

Comment: my question is not about the error, why its not going to secue page

Comment: That's what I answered: It's not going to the secure page because of the 401 for the favion.ico!

Comment: i have permited in both Auth Serve and Client, now 401 error is not coming both problem is solved. code is updated in Git

Comment: so you are redirect now, right? If yes I will post that as answer

Comment: i am sorry my bad.. its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184321/discussion-between-chiranjeevigk-and-simon-martinelli).

Comment: which URL are you trying to access now ?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/